# Why if a real function has a derivative with a positive lower bound, it must be surjective

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and suppose that $f'(x)\ge c >0$ for all $x$. Show that for each $y\in \Bbb R$, there is an unique $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

By assumption and mean value theorem, $f$ is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$. If I can prove $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. Then by definition, Given $y>0$, there exist $t_0$ and $t_1$ such that $f(t_0)>y$ and $f(t_1)<-y<y$. By intermediate value theorem, there exists $z$ between $t_0$ and $t_1$ such that $f(z)=y$, and since $f$ is strictly increasing, this $z$ is unique. We can do it for any $y\in \Bbb R$, so we are done.

I want to ask how to prove $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x >0$ we have $f(x)-f(0)=xf'(t)$ for some $t$ between $0$ and $x$.Hence $f(x) \geq f(0)+cx \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Similarly. $f(0)-f(-x)=xf'(s)$ for some $s$ between $0$ and $-x$ and this gives $f(-x) \to -\infty$ as $ x \to \infty$.

Comment: You mean $f(x)\ge f(0)+cx\to\infty$.